remove starting hashes in bash script
I am writing a bash script. want to remove starting hashes(#)
input file: test.txt text
#### FEATURE-MERGE
some db changes

#### FEATURE-TESTING-WEBHOOK
some other plain text

#### FEATURE-PREHOOK
some explaination 

#### FEATURE-SPLIT KV PAIR LOG LINE
some text


what i have tried:
users@5830:$ cat test.txt | grep -i "FEATURE-"
#### FEATURE-MERGE
#### FEATURE-TESTING-WEBHOOK
#### FEATURE-PREHOOK
#### FEATURE-SPLIT KV PAIR LOG LINE

desired output:
FEATURE-MERGE
FEATURE-TESTING-WEBHOOK
FEATURE-PREHOOK
FEATURE-SPLIT KV PAIR LOG LINE


do you have lines that start with # that do not contain the string FEATURE-? if 'yes' then please update the data (sample input, expected output) to show such a line

please update the question with the code you've tried and the (wrong) results generated by your code

Use sed to remove the hashes.
cat test.txt | grep -i "FEATURE-" | sed -e 's/^#### //'

The s/.../.../ is a substitution and replaces everything between the first two slashes with the characters between the middle slash and the last one. The ^ means "beginning of the line". You may or may not need it here, depending on whether four hashes show up elsewhere in your data.
(You can also use different characters instead of slashes to mark the groups in the substitution, e.g., if the pattern to replace contains slashes: sed -e 's@####@@'.)
The single quotes around the sed expression are needed so that the shell doesn't do word splitting in the space or tries to interpret the hashes as comments.

That's both a useless cat and a useless grep. sed -n '/[Ff][Ee][Aa][Tt][Uu][Rr][Ee]-/s/^#### //p' test.txt if you genuinely want to remove all other lines, or more probably just s/^#### //' test.txt if I understand the OP correctly.

@tripleee Yes, good point. I just kept cat and grep cause OP had them.
